# Azure SignalR Service Error - Message rate reaches limit

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-signalr

Using Azure SignalR service.

Message rate - 1 messages per 100 milliseconds.

Getting error in C# client which send message to Azure SignalR service.

connected successfully and able to receive and send messages but after some time(5 seconds) getting error on sender side continuously - "The server closed the connection with the following error: Message rate reaches limit."

Trying to reconnect in OnClose event but getting same error continuously.

The Azure SignalR receiver client work properly without disconnect but getting issue in sender client.

From Azure SignalR metrics is there any way to see it's message limits or per second limit?

It work properly if i host asp.net core SignalrR in web app instead of using Azure SignalR.

This issue occur with both Azure SignalR Free and Standard(Paid) Tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design, The limit as of now is 5 message/second. So in your case, service detected that the clients are sending data too fast and disconnect them.

git hub issue for same - https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/149